# Is there something between the 78LXX and 78XX, current wise?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I'm trying to find a 5V regulator that is smaller than the 7805, but the 78L05, while nice and small, is too low current. Ideally, I would like 500mA. Is there something that is also through hole (sadly, surface mount is out). Does anything like this exist?

Comment: What's the input voltage? I'm just wondering if something like the Murata 7805SR switching replacement while slightly larger would end up being smaller for your application by not needing a heatsink.

Comment: 9-20V input. Wow... that's expensive. Unfortunately, needs to be way cheaper than that.

Comment: How do you plan to get rid of the heat?

Comment: Currently, the 7805 is laid flat and has a copper pad on the board for a heat sink

Answer (score 3):

The 78Mxx are rated at 500mA, so fit neatly between the 100mA of the 78Lxx and the 1A of the 78xx.

Answer (score 1):

The Texas Instruments TPS7350QP is available [from Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=TPS7350QP) in single quantities for $2.68, has a 500 mA output current and most importantly, comes in an 8-pin DIP package (area wise, about a third the size of a TO-220 laid flat).  Unfortunately, LDO regulators in TO-92 packages (typically used for discrete transistors) only go up to a maximum of 250 mA in current output.)

I also found a buck converter in an 8-pin DIP package: the LM2574 available [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM2574N-5.0%2FNOPB/LM2574N-5.0%2FNOPB-ND/212613) for $1.99, which will be a lot more efficient than a linear regulator.  The downside, is that like all buck or boost converters, you need an inductor [like this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/744732331/732-3751-ND/3073909) which costs $1.50 and takes additional space.

Comment: Buck converter modules with inductors built in are available in a TO-220 form factor which is designed to serve as a drop-in replacement for the 7805.  Not sure if smaller prefab modules are readily available.